# KeyError in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this YAML file which I want validate before further actions. This is an example of a file used. I want to test it against a regex to prevent special characters be added in the **contacts** label.

```
api_version: core/v2
metadata:
  annotations: {}
  labels:
    contacts: Test-contact TEST
  name: testing
  namespace: default
```

This is the code I'm using to load the file

```
data_yaml = yaml.safe_load_all(f)
list_data_yaml = list(data_yaml)
```

And this is the part that is failing

```
wrong_names = [dictionary['metadata']['labels']['contacts'] for dictionary in list_data_yaml if                        
                       regex.search(dictionary['metadata']['labels']['contacts']) is not None]
if wrong_names:
  print(f"ERROR: Cannot have special characters (@!#$%^&*()<>?/\ \\|) in the contacts label. Contact label = {wrong_names}")
return False
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
regex.search(dictionary['metadata']['labels']['contacts']) is not None]
KeyError: 'contacts'
```

Any ideas?

P.S. For more detail, this piece of code is fully functional (it sits above the one in the original post)

```
wrong_names = [dictionary['metadata']['name'] for dictionary in list_data_yaml if
                       regex.search(dictionary['metadata']['name']) is not None]
if wrong_names:
  print(f"ERROR: Cannot have special characters (@!#$%^&*()<>?/\\|) in check name. Check name = {wrong_names}")
return False
```

Comment: You're not asking a question. You don't even provide a simple [mcve], let alone tell us what you expect to happen as outcome. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Hi Urlich, my question was about accesing the third layer of a nested dict, and why this was not working, even though the file contained that value. I didn't consider a reproducible example was necessary in this scenario, so that's my bad.

Comment: For something this small, there is really no reason to *not* provide a complete example (for example, you haven't told us which YAML library you are using). Include the YAML data as a string literal. Omit everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem. When I load the YAML you show, using pyyaml, I can access 'contacts'.

Comment: Hi Ture, I am using also the PyYAML lib
`import yaml`

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `Try..Except` the KeyError error

```py
try:
    wrong_names = [dictionary['metadata']['labels']['contacts'] for dictionary in list_data_yaml if
                   regex.search(dictionary['metadata']['labels']['contacts']) is not None]
    if wrong_names:
        print(f"ERROR: Cannot have special characters (@!#$%^&*()<>?/\ \\|) in the contacts label. Contact label = {wrong_names}")
    return False

except KeyError:
    # Do something when there is no 'contacts'
    pass
```

Or, you can use [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Comment: Hi Thy, thanks for the input! I have tried that, and indeed it works, but it bypass all this validation step. Can you refer back to the original question, I have added an additional small piece of code which is functional.

Comment: Does your YAML file always have `contacts` key? If it doesn't, I guess you can bypass the validation and return an error.

Comment: Yes, I have a schema template for this and the contacts field is mandatory